# mysql many to many delete cascade leaves orphans

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, cascade, orphan

World!

I'm having orphans when I cascade delete records in a many to many relationship. This is my sql code (for mysql):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS skTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS studentTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS classTable;

create table if not exists classTable (id int primary key) ENGINE=INNODB;
insert into classTable values(1);
insert into classTable values(2);

create table if not exists studentTable (id int primary key, classID int, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES classTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)  ENGINE=INNODB;
insert into studentTable values(1, 1);
insert into studentTable values(2, 2);

create table if not exists kTable (id int primary key) ENGINE=INNODB;
insert into kTable values(1);
insert into kTable values(2);
insert into kTable values(3);

create table if not exists skTable (id int primary key, studentID int, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(studentID) REFERENCES studentTable(id) on delete cascade, kID int, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(kID) REFERENCES kTable(id) on delete cascade) ENGINE=INNODB;
insert into skTable values(1,1,1);
insert into skTable values(2,2,2);
insert into skTable values(3,2,3);
insert into skTable values(4,1,2);

DELETE FROM classTable WHERE id=2;
```

My expectation is to get these records:

classTable, 1 record:

```
    id=1
```

studentTable, 1 record:

```
    id=1, classID=1
```

kTable, 2 records:

```
    id=1
    id=2
```

skTable, 2 records:

```
    id=1, studentID=1, kID=1
    id=4, studentID=1, kID=2
```

The problem is that at the end kTable has the extra record

```
    id=3
```

which is orphan.

Any idea?
Thanks. L

Answer (score 0):

In your example `skTable` is child for `studentTable` and `kTable`. And `studentTable` is child for `classTable`.
For foriegn key ON DELETE CASCADE, if you delete in parent then child table data will delete. But vise versa is not possible. That is why, when you delete data in `classTable`, `studentTable` data is deleted and because of data delete in `studentTable`, `skTable` data is deleted but not `kTable` data.

Comment: Thanks Phaneendra, now I understand the problem better. Is there any option to design it better or all I can do is to manage the orphans by trigger or my code?